# Reiniciar - Borrar stack Android

Tags: java, android

El stack de una aplicación mobile , una vez llegada al "Home" partiendo como esta el " inicio " , una vez echo unos flujos de x cantidad de actividades , que seria lo correcto:

Volver a mandarlo al **HOME** por medio de `intents` , o tener que hacerle un `go back` hasta el home , el stack se reinicia o se limpia una vez echo un start intent o la única forma de sacarle al stack es volviendo para atrás? , existe algún método para limpiar el stack ?

Desde ya gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien quieres quitar de la pila las actividades previas almacenadas.

Hay una bandera que puedes pasar al Intent cuando vayas al Home.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias carlos